# How to update table by applying row wise condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table as Shown below

```
col1    california    florida     hawaii     date
=================================================
a1      32            86            23         Jan
a2      67            63            8990       Jan
a3      86            453           6          Jan
b1      54            876           7868       Jan
b2      6             786           75         Jan
b3      988           56            876        Jan
c1      1             2344          6          Jan
c2      876           57            986        Jan
c3      12            67            76         Jan
a1      0             0             0          feb
a2      0             0             0          feb
a3      0             0             0          feb
b1      0             0             0          feb
b2      0             0             0          feb
b3      0             0             0          feb
c1      1             3             67         feb
c2      9             7             32         feb
c3      12            67            76         feb
a1      0             0             0          mar
a2      0             0             0          mar
a3      0             0             0          mar
b1      0             0             0          mar
b2      0             0             0          mar
b3      0             0             0          mar
c1      66            2             9          mar
c2      32            7             1          mar
c3      12            67            76         mar
```

Now i want to update every a1=b1=c1 and a2=b2=c2 and a3=b3=c3 monthwise for every state if they are empty

i want logic like given below for every month

```
if(a1==0) then a1=c1
if(a2==0) then a2=c2
if(a3==0) then a3=c3

if(b1==0) then b1=c1
if(b2==0) then b2=c2
if(b3==0) then b3=c3
```

how to write the query for this.. ?

my required output is

```
col1    california    florida     hawaii     date
=================================================
a1      32            86            23         Jan
a2      67            63            8990       Jan
a3      86            453           6          Jan
b1      54            876           7868       Jan
b2      6             786           75         Jan
b3      988           56            876        Jan
c1      1             2344          6          Jan
c2      876           57            986        Jan
c3      12            67            76         Jan
a1      1             3             67         feb
a2      9             7             32         feb
a3      12            67            76         feb
b1      1             3             67         feb
b2      9             7             32         feb
b3      12            67            76         feb
c1      1             3             67         feb
c2      9             7             32         feb
c3      12            67            76         feb
a1      66            2             9          mar
a2      32            7             1          mar
a3      12            67            76         mar
b1      66            2             9          mar
b2      32            7             1          mar
b3      12            67            76         mar
c1      66            2             9          mar
c2      32            7             1          mar
c3      12            67            76         mar
```

Comment: Use case and put all as conditions for this

Comment: `if(a1==0) then a1=c1`. Which `c1`? Mention the expected output clearly.

Comment: Please write the output you want

Comment: It's not entirely clear, at least not to me, what you are trying to achieve. Can you also post how the table will look like *after* the `UPDATE` has taken place?

Comment: Also, row order seems to play an important role in the `UPDATE`. Since there *no inherent* row order in any SQL table, what is the column that determines row order in your case?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I think he wants to fill the zero missing data with the values from the first 9 records.  But in my mind, I would rather have inserted the missing data from scratch.

Comment: plzz let me edit this

Comment: I'd first look at fixing the data structure rather than trying to work with it as-is. A normalized table here would contain five columns - `month, state, <whatever a,b or c represents in col1>, <whatever 1,2 or 3 represents in col1>, <whatever is currently represented across the 3 state columns>`. This current structure is a mess and is only going to cause continual problems with every query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know this structure is not good but i have to do this task. I don't have access to change the structure of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE to do the `UPDATE`:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT t1.col1, t1.california, t1.florida, t1.hawaii, t1.[date],  
          t2.california AS california_2, t2.florida AS florida_2, t2.hawaii AS hawaii_2
   FROM mytable AS t1
   JOIN mytable AS t2 
      ON t1.[date] = t2.[date] AND 
         (((t1.col1 IN ('a1', 'b1')) AND (t2.col1 = 'c1')) OR 
         ((t1.col1 IN ('a2', 'b2')) AND (t2.col1 = 'c2')) OR
         ((t1.col1 IN ('a3', 'b3')) AND (t2.col1 = 'c3')))
   WHERE t1.california = 0 AND t1.florida = 0 AND t1.hawaii = 0 AND
         t1.col1 IN ('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3')
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET california = california_2,
    florida = florida_2,
    hawaii = hawaii_2
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/QKR14141)

Comment: Thank you so muchh... Working perfect :)

Comment: @Giorgos: Sir, I'm not able to understand what's the need of "AND t1.col1 IN ('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3')" in WHERE clause. Can you please make me a little wiser?

Comment: @SachinA The OP wants to only do an `UPDATE` when `col1 IN ('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3')`.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, I would rather just do a repeat insert of the data you do have into a new table:

```
CREATE PROC YourProc
DECLARE @Loop INT

AS

SET @Loop = 2
WHILE @Loop > 0
BEGIN

INSERT INTO newTable (col1, california, florida, hawaii)
SELECT DISTINCT col1, california, florida, hawaii   
FROM yourTable

SET @Loop = @Loop - 1
END
```